# XRlibrary is locked by another concurrent conan process, wait... in c++

Tags: conan

While building my solution in VS, am getting conan lock error in c++

```
1>  XRLibrary/0.1@Xerox/XRLibrary is locked by another concurrent conan process, wait...
1>  If not the case, quit, and do 'conan remove --locks'
9>  perfmon.cpp
```

Comment: did you run `conan remove --locks`?  It's not an error, it occurred because or some build was stopped abruptly, or you tried to build the same package twice at same time.

Comment: yes i ran lock command, cache lock remved  message am getting, i gave clean build still the issue is there.

Comment: i deleted all the packages manually in the folder structure of conan path, and gave clean build. Now solution is building.

Comment: I see, but probably only removing your package would be enough `conan remove -f XRLibrary/0.1@Xerox/XRLibrary`. The recipe folder could contain a lock file which is not removed by `remove --locks`

Comment: @uilianries I can confirm conan remove --locks doesn't do anything, and conan remove -f couldn't even find the directory to remove the file from.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem with installing Sentry.io's packages. I did it on Windows, steps might be similar for Linux as well.

Make sure you have the latest version of Conan. Typically you can run the following (if conan was installed using pip):

`pip install --upgrade conan`

You can do the following next:

- Remove directory `/c/Users/TestUser/.conan/data/<some-package>` (Here the some-package might be XRLibrary)
- Rerun your `conan install` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a mac user, just remove `~/.conan/data`. That works for me.